# How to use ssl-root-cas with axios

Tags: node.js, https, axios

I'm trying to use axios to make GET requests, but am getting:

*Error: unable to verify the first certificate*

From what I've found so far, ssl-root-cas should solve this, but I can't figure out how to apply it to axios. One doc I read said that I need to pass it as an agent to axios, but that didn't help me much. I've tried stuff like:

```
var rootCas = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();
var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;
var axios = require('axios');
axios.agent = rootCas; //also tried = https, but I think I'm misunderstanding
```